# Aurelia binding for child elements

Tags: aurelia

I have a couple custom elements laid out like this

```html
<panel label="Label">
   <row-panel title="Row1">
      <button field="Row1" command="Label"></button>        
   </row-panel>
</panel>
```

Is there a way to use the title attribute "label" value of row-panel in the button attribute value for "field"?

Is there a way to use the panel attribute "label" value as the button "command" attribute value?

Ideally, I'd like the markup to look like this if possible.

```html
<panel label="Label">
   <row-panel title="Row1">
      <button></button>        
   </row-panel>
</panel>
```

and the button element would inherit its field and command attributes from the two elements above it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property and bind it to all elements. Like this:

```
<panel label.bind="myProperty">
   <row-panel title.bind="myProperty">
      <button field.bind="myProperty"></button>        
   </row-panel>
</panel>
```

Comment: The consumer of the custom elements need to be able to set those attributes on the panel and row-panel. I was just hoping I could reuse what they entered into the button attributes. I think your way would be where the myProperty is set in the view-model?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question... You could declare myProperty in the viewModel